# What does "Authentication" mean creating key with Kleopatra?

Tags: pgp, openpgp, gpg4win, kleopatra

What does "Authentication" mean creating key with Kleopatra ? (see image)
The image is in french sorry, please help me

[image: kleopatra]

Comment: you can learn more about certificate usages and extended usages here: https://datacadamia.com/crypto/certificate/usage . Usages are a type of x.509 extension (an attribute added to the certificate) to tell systems that work with it what it is intended to be used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly, this usage is for subkeys that would be used as SSH keys via gpg-agent's "SSH agent emulation" feature – so it's similar to how your ~/.ssh/id_rsa is an authentication key. (In theory it could also be used for authentication in other protocols, but in practice it's just SSH really.)

(The usage is separate from "Signature" because authentication keys are typically used to create very short-term signatures that are only meaningful within a particular handshake, so the requirements for key protection are slightly different. For example, a smart-card might require a PIN for *every* signature from a signing key, but only require a PIN every hour for an authentication key.)